# Import Excel data into an existing SQL Server 2005 table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, import

I'm trying to import some data from an Excel sheet into an existing SQL Server 2005 table.

The table has the following columns:

```
Name, Surname, PhoneNumber ,Bill
```

and they are in the same order in the Excel sheet.

I've never attempted such a thing before, but after searching for a while I was told I could use:

```
INSERT INTO table 
    SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
                             'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\temp\test.xls',
                             'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Do I need to reference the column names from the Excel sheet to the SQL Server table columns?

I'm certainly not a SQL guru, but would consider myself a good beginner.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried using the import utility built into SQL Management Studio?  That gives you the ability to map your columns correctly.

Comment: Does that feature exist in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express 9.00.5000.00?

Comment: I can't find it anywhere...unless I'm going blind

Comment: for 2008 and up, yes it does

Comment: Hmm..  I honestly don't know.  I have the 10.5 version here.  In the Object Explorer, I can click on the database in question, and got to "Tasks/import".  I would guess something similar was in version 9.

Comment: Right click on database, go to `Task` than `Import Data` on new screen there should be drop down to select `Excel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here in you Management Studio 
:
Choose you db?
[image]

Choose your source :
[image]

and from here is all just following the GUI !!

Comment: This feature isn't available on my test server (SQL Express) however I can see this feature on the live environment. but getting the following error when I tried this: Error 0xc00470fe: Data Flow Task: The product level is insufficient for component "Source - Sheet1$ (1).
Any ideas what this could be?

Comment: do you have SSIS installed on your machine, fix this by applying a service pack.

Comment: How can I check if I have SSIS? On the live server I have version 9.00.1399.00